# List contents of shared drive directory

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I can list contents of directories under wwwroot or application folder, but am having a hard time listing the directories of a shared drive. \remotedrive\dir_to_list.
There must be an equivalent to _hostenvironment.WebRootPath. Any suggestions? I am new to ASP.NET core so please be complete as possible with response.

```
private IWebHostEnvironment _hostenvironment;
         
public FilesController(IWebHostEnvironment hostenvironment)
{
    _hostenvironment = hostenvironment;
}

public IActionResult Index()
{
    string[] filepaths = Directory.GetFiles(Path.Combine(_hostenvironment.WebRootPath, "/"));
    List<FileViewModel> lstFiles = new List<FileViewModel>();
    foreach (var file in filepaths)
    {
        lstFiles.Add(new FileViewModel { FileName = Path.GetFileName(file) });
    }
    return View(lstFiles);
}
```

Comment: Why would there be an equivalent to WebRootPath for a shared drive? What drive are you connecting to? Do you have the full path to it? What's wrong with just using that path in your System.IO calls?

Comment: Asp.net running with a session? Because I am not sure you can connect outside without a session and with the limited rights you have as a mvc app.

Comment: Hi Mason , do you mean like this string[] filepaths = Directory.GetFiles(Path.GetFullPath("\\\\TQFPRK06\\"));

Comment: If I put just c: , it returns the contents of the c: directory but it doesn't like the \\TQFPRK06\ .

Comment: If I use the mapped drive letter as J:\\filedir\\ , it works but the problems is I don't know what letter is mapped to everyones computer.

Comment: I don't see the directory list with J:\\ only a thumbs.db DUH I had to use getdirectories

Comment: Sooo.. close the question as "caused by a typo" ?

Comment: Question isn't answered yet as I still can't access the drive directories by "\\\\TQFPRK06\\"

Comment: I don't know if the session affects the fact our company uses windows authentication to give drive permissions. I any event it doesn't give authentification error , just that it can't find the drive specified. (In "\\\\TQFPRK06\\" format.)